# Show photo in sidebar from google places api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-places-api

Here I create a code that will show places from google places api in map and sidebar.

But I dont know how to show places without photo in sidebar and shw information about this

look this: http://jsbin.com/umaruq/1 , so when I type "bars" on map show all bars, but in sidebar I cant get bars without photos

SOURCE CODE: http://jsbin.com/umaruq/1/edit DEMO: http://jsbin.com/umaruq/1

I think that is the problem in this code:

```
 $("#side_bar").empty();
      for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
        if (place.photos) {
          markers.push(new PhotoMarker(place, map, modalWindow));
          setLink(i);              
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        } else {
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: place.geometry.location,
            map: map,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                'http://carsedia.com/code/voyage/icons/7.png',
                null, null, new google.maps.Point(3.5,3.5)),
            clickable: false
          }));
        } 
      }
```

I was try with :   `if (place.name)` but there is error

Is there any way to solve this and show all places (with photo and without photo) in sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

You put the link only if you have a photo.
You can try something like :

```
  for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
    if (place.photos) {
      markers.push(new PhotoMarker(place, map, modalWindow));
      setLink(i, true);              
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    } else {
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: place.geometry.location,
        map: map,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            'http://carsedia.com/code/voyage/icons/7.png',
            null, null, new google.maps.Point(3.5,3.5)),
        clickable: false
      }));
      /* if no photo, put false as 2nd argument */
      setLink(i, false);              
    } 
  }
```

And edit your "setLink" function :

```
function setLink(i, has_photo) {
    var photo = has_photo ? place.photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 50, 'maxHeight': 50 }) : 'http://carsedia.com/code/voyage/icons/7.png';
    var sideClick = jQuery("<a class=side_click href='#'></a>");
    $(sideClick).html(place.name+place.opening_hours);
    $("#side_bar").append(sideClick).append("<br>").append("<div class='draggable'><img src="+photo+" style='width:50px'></img></div><br><p></p>");
    $(sideClick).on("click", function() {
        markers[i].modalWindow_.getDetails(markers[i].place_);
    });
 }
```

Look at : http://jsbin.com/umaruq/3

Comment: yes, thanks, but when I click on sidebar place which dont contain photo I dont get anything... so I can click on that link on sidebar, so I dont have any info about that places...